# <b-modal> is showing as text when using bootstrap-vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I'm building a modal, to edit an object from a table, but when calling a example modal, it's showing as a text. As in this image bellow:

[image]

Here is the code example:

```
    <!-- Using value -->
    <b-button v-b-modal="'my-modal'">Show Modal</b-button>

    <!-- The modal -->
    <b-modal id="my-modal">Hello From My Modal!</b-modal>
```

This is strange, because v-for and v-model are working normaly, but `<b-alert>` and `<b-modal>` aren't.

Comment: Did you import bootstrap vue?

Comment: Yes, i imported like that:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="resources/css/bootstrap-vue.css">

Comment: @M.Alves That's just the CSS. You need to import the `bootstrap-vue` javascript file as well.

Comment: Sorry i was import the JS incorrectly, now it is working well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've imported the `v-b-modal` directive. Here's the working code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- Using value -->
        <b-button v-b-modal="'my-modal'">Show Modal</b-button>

        <!-- The modal -->
        <b-modal id="my-modal">Hello From My Modal!</b-modal>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { BButton, BModal, VBModal } from "bootstrap-vue";

    export default {
        components: {
            BButton,
            BModal
        },

        directives: { 
            'b-modal': VBModal 
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error, with or withouth it: 
"vue.js:616 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: b-modal"

Comment: As mentioned by Hiws, make sure you imported the javascript file. For more information [link](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/#browser)